# COBOL outputting a blank file instead of expected output

Tags: cobol, mainframe, jcl

Hey guys I've been scratching my head over this all day to no avail. I'm running a COBOl program that *should* take input from one file and output it to another if it meets some conditions.
This is the `PROCEDURE DIVISION.`

```
 PROCEDURE DIVISION.
      *
       A000-START.
           OPEN INPUT CUST-RECS.
           OPEN OUTPUT ACCT-RPT.
           PERFORM A000-WRITE-FIRST.
           PERFORM READ-NEXT-RECORD.
      *    PERFORM WRITE-RECORD.
           CLOSE ACCT-RPT.
           CLOSE CUST-RECS.
           STOP RUN.
      *
       A000-WRITE-FIRST.
           DISPLAY "WRITE-FIRST".
           MOVE 2 TO REC-COUNT.
           WRITE PRT-REP-DONE FROM HEADER-1.
           WRITE PRT-REP-DONE FROM HEADER-2.
           WRITE PRT-REP-DONE FROM HEADER-3.
           WRITE PRT-REP-DONE FROM HEADER-4.
      *
       READ-NEXT-RECORD.
           PERFORM READ-RECORD
              PERFORM UNTIL LASTREC = 'Y'
              PERFORM WRITE-RECORD
              PERFORM READ-RECORD
              END-PERFORM.
      *
       WRITE-RECORD.
           DISPLAY "WRITE-RECORD called" FIRST-NAME.
           MOVE SPACES TO PRT-REP-DONE.
           MOVE REC-COUNT TO PRT-RECS.
           MOVE FIRST-NAME TO PRT-NAME-FST.
           MOVE LAST-NAME TO PRT-NAME-LST.
           MOVE BALANCE TO PRT-BALANCE.
           WRITE PRT-REP-DONE.
           CLOSE ACCT-RPT.
       
       READ-RECORD.
           READ CUST-RECS
           AT END MOVE 'Y' TO LASTREC

           IF (FUNCTION NUMVAL-C(BALANCE) IS > 8500000)
              THEN
                 DISPLAY "BALANCE: " BALANCE
                 ADD 1 TO REC-COUNT
                 PERFORM WRITE-RECORD
           END-IF
           END-READ.
```

In my output file I just get 1 blank line. And a ABEND code of SB14. I was able to get some output before but now nothing.

Comment: According to the description of `sb14`, either there is no space in the output PDS or there is no space in the Directory. Have a look at the output file, If it is a PDS, I would suggest compressing it. If you are using a PDS as output, it needs to be compressed regularly to reclaim unused space. See https://ibmmainframes.com/about23872.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SB14 is an issue with close.  SB14 can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.4.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r4.ieah700/m014719.htm)  This abend indicates there is the accompanying messace [IEC217I](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.ieam700/ee217i.htm)

[image]

With regard to the code, it looks like you're closing the output file `ACCT-RPT` `WRITE-RECORD` which is probably your output file.

> ```
>    WRITE-RECORD.
>        DISPLAY "WRITE-RECORD called" FIRST-NAME.
>        MOVE SPACES TO PRT-REP-DONE.
>        MOVE REC-COUNT TO PRT-RECS.
>        MOVE FIRST-NAME TO PRT-NAME-FST.
>        MOVE LAST-NAME TO PRT-NAME-LST.
>        MOVE BALANCE TO PRT-BALANCE.
>        WRITE PRT-REP-DONE.
>        CLOSE ACCT-RPT.
> ```

My guess is its whining about `closing` the file twice.

Comment: Thank you man. I- I don't even know how I missed that. Thank you a ton.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no COBOL man, but your code looks very incorrect to me. `WRITE-RECORD` is called from `READ-NEXT-RECORD`, as well as from `READ-RECORD`. But that is not the main problem.

The reason there is only one record in the output is the `CLOSE ACCT-RPT` in `WRITE-RECORD`. Closing and reopening a dataset will overwrite previous content every time the data set is reopened (unless you have DISP=MOD on the DD statement).

You seem to be writing to a PDS member, and all the closing and reopening finally uses all the space which leads to the B14 ABEND.

Rethink your logic.